# Form submission via Ajax - POST empty

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm experimenting with Ajax with PHP and I'm missing the last link in the chain - Getting the data back after submitting. I'm trying to use an Ajax request with the type: POST.

I'm printing the response data to console, and getting a string that looks like this:

`projectName=Test+Project&type=1&providerName=Test+Provider&completeLink=link1&quotaFullLink=link2&screenoutLink=link3`

However, if I do a `var_dump($_POST);` it returns empty. Since I'm using `type: "POST"` in my ajax settings, I was expecting the post variable to be populated with the data from the form.

The form POST target's itself.

Apologies if this is a really stupid misunderstanding of how Ajax requests work. The code is working, however in the snippet the function that shows/hides parts of the form isn't working.

**Javascript, CSS, HTML/PHP**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

 document.getElementById("typeNew").checked = false;
    
 var request;

 $("#createPanelForm").submit(function(event){

  if (request) {
   request.abort();
  }

  var $form = $(this);

  var $inputs = $form.find("projectName, type, providerName, completeLink, quotaFullLink, screenoutLink, existingProvider");

  var serializedData = $form.serialize();

  $inputs.prop("disabled", true);

  request = $.ajax({
   url: "createpanel.php",
   type: "POST",
   data: serializedData
  });

  request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR){
   console.log(serializedData);
  });

  request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
  
   console.error(
    "The following error occurred: "+
    textStatus, errorThrown
   );
  });

  request.always(function () {
   $inputs.prop("disabled", false);
  });

  event.preventDefault();
  
  $("#createPanelForm").fadeOut(1000);
  $("#submitResponse").delay(1001).fadeIn(1000);  
 });

})
```

```css
body {
 margin-top: 50px; /* 50px is the height of the navbar - change this if the navbarn height changes */
}

.childnav {
 background-color: #d11717;
 text-align: left;
}

.logo-wrapper {
 display: inline-block;
}

.section {
 padding-top: 40px;
 padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.section-heading {
 font-size: 4em;
 margin: 30px 0;
}

.section-lead {
 margin: 30px 0;
}

.section-paragraph {
 margin: 30px 0;
}

footer {
 margin: 50px 0;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {

.section-heading {
 font-size: 2em;
}

.section {
 padding-top: 25px;
 padding-bottom: 25px;
}
.highlight {
padding: 9px 14px;
margin-bottom: 14px;
background-color: #f7f7f9;
border: 1px solid #e1e1e8;
border-radius: 4px;
}
.delete {
margin-top:5px;
    background:url(../images/delete.png) no-repeat;
    cursor:pointer;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    border: none;
 display:inline;
}
.back {
margin-top:5px;
    background:url(../images/back.png) no-repeat;
    cursor:pointer;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    border: none;
 display:inline;
}
.edit {
margin-top:5px;
    background:url(../images/edit.png) no-repeat;
    cursor:pointer;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    border: none;
 display:inline;
}
.printPage {
margin-top:5px;
    background:url(../images/print.png) no-repeat;
    cursor:pointer;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    border: none;
 display:inline;
}
.projectComplete {
margin-top:5px;
    background:url(../images/complete.png) no-repeat;
    cursor:pointer;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    border: none;
 display:inline;
}
.excel {
margin-top:5px;
    background:url(../images/excel.png) no-repeat;
    cursor:pointer;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    border: none;
 display:inline;
}
.singleShift {
    margin-top:5px;
    background:url(../images/page.png) no-repeat;
    cursor:pointer;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    border: none;
 display:inline;
}
.search {
    margin-top:5px;
    background:url(../images/search.png) no-repeat;
    cursor:pointer;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
 margin-top:2px;
    border: none;
 display:inline;
}
#query {
margin-top: 10px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
}
.dantable {
background-color: #ffffff;
border: 1px solid #c5251d;
text-align:center;
border-radius:4px;
}
.tweets {
background-color: #ffffff;
border: 1px solid #c5251d;
border-radius:4px;
}
th {
text-align:center;
}
.src_drop{
font-size:11px;
padding:4px 2px;
border:solid 1px #c5251d;
width:160px;
height:28px;
display:inline;
margin-bottom:0px;
border-radius:3px;
}
.src_date{
font-size:11px;
padding:4px 2px;
padding-left: 4px;
border:solid 1px #c5251d;
width:100px;
height:28px;
display:inline;
margin-bottom:0px;
border-radius:3px;
}
.sidewidget {
margin-top:15px;
font-weight:bold;
text-align:center;
margin-bottom: 2px;
}
.page_head {
margin-top:15px;
font-weight:bold;
text-align:center;
margin-bottom: 2px;
border-bottom: 1px solid #c5251d;
}
#pagin {
    opacity:0.5;
 font-size: 12px;
 margin-top: 3px;
}
.col-centered{
float: none;
margin: 0 auto;
}
.center {
margin-left: 0 auto;
margin-right: 0 auto;
}
.bclinks:hover {
color:fff;
}
.testlabel {
font-size: 13px;
}
.dantest {
float:right;
display:inline-block;
}
#footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
.notification {
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  background:#FF0000;
  height: 20px;
  width:22px;
  border-radius:5px;
  color: white;
  /*font-weight: bold; */
  text-align: center;
  /* padding-right:2px; */
}
.notification_link{
  position:absolute; 
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  top:0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.notification_img {
border: 1px solid #c5251d;
margin-right: 5px;
}

.notification_msg {
 padding-bottom: 15px;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #D3D3D3;
   margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.notification_msg_last {

}

.notification_actions {
   color: #D3D3D3;
}

.notification_actions > a:link {
   color: #D3D3D3;
}
.btn-notify {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #f0ad4e;
  border-color: #eea236;
}
.btn-notify :hover,
.btn-notify :focus,
.btn-notify :active,
.btn-notify .active,
.open .dropdown-toggle.btn-notify  {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #ed9c28;
  border-color: #d58512;
}
.edit_textinput {
 -webkit-appearance:none;
 -moz-appearance:none;
 appearance:none;
 outline:none;
 border:none;
 border-style:none;
 height:19px;
 width:100%;
}
#existingProviderInput {
 display:none;
}
#newProviderInput {
 display:none;
}
#submitResponse {
 display:none;
 text-align:center;
 margin-left:-5%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
               
  <?php include("includes/notifications.php"); ?>   
      

 <div class="col-lg-7 section">
  <div class="highlight">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-8 col-centered">
    <!-- Content Container -->
    <div id="createPanel">
     <form id="createPanelForm" class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" action="createpanel.php";>
       <fieldset>
      <p class="page_head" style="margin-bottom:5%">Set up a new project</p>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="projectName" class="col-lg-3 control-label">Project name</label>
        <div class="col-lg-9">
       <input type="text" class="form-control" name="projectName" id="projectName" placeholder="Enter name of project">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Panel type</label>
        <div class="col-lg-9">
       <div class="radio">
         <label>
        <input type="radio" onclick="javascript:newOrExisting();" name="type" id="typeNew" value="1" checked="">
        New provider
         </label>
       </div>
       <div class="radio">
         <label>
        <input type="radio" onclick="javascript:newOrExisting();" name="type" id="typeExisting" value="2">
        Existing provider
         </label>
       </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="newProviderInput">
       <div class="form-group">
         <label for="providerName" class="col-lg-3 control-label">Provider name</label>
         <div class="col-lg-9">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="providerName" id="providerName" placeholder="Enter name of company">
         </div>
       </div>
       <div class="form-group">
         <label for="completeLink" class="col-lg-3 control-label">Redirect links</label>
         <div class="col-lg-9">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="completeLink" id="completeLink" placeholder="Enter completion link">
        <br />
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="quotaFullLink" id="quotaFullLink" placeholder="Enter quota full link">
        <br />
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="screenoutLink" id="screenoutLink" placeholder="Enter screenout link">
         </div>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div id="existingProviderInput">
       <div class="form-group">
         <label for="select" class="col-lg-3 control-label">Provider</label>
         <div class="col-lg-9">
        <select class="form-control" name="existingProvider" id="existingProvider">
          <option value="" disabled selected>Select an existing provider</option>
          <option>All Global</option>
          <option>Cint</option>
          <option>Barcode</option>
          <option>Research Now</option>
          <option>Research Opinions</option>
        </select>
         </div>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-lg-9 col-lg-offset-3">
        <br />
       <button type="reset" onclick="clearForm();" class="btn btn-default">Reset</button>
       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      
       </fieldset>
     </form>
    </div>
    
    <div id="submitResponse">
     <p class="page_head" style="margin-bottom:5%">Form has been submitted</p>
     
     <div id="submitSuccess">
      <p align="center">
       <img style="margin-right:1%" src="images/complete.png"/>
       Success!
      </p>
      <p>
       Display the submitted details here
      </p>
     </div>
     
     <div id="submitError">
      <p align="center">
       <img style="margin-right:1%" src="images/delete.png"/>
       Error!
      </p>
      <p>
       Display details of the error here
      </p>
     </div>   
     
    </div>
    <!-- End of Content Container -->
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: We really do not need css code

Comment: @nospor Sorry, never used the code snippet thing before, didn't know it was going to show everything on the page :P

Comment: I don't see you using `$_POST` anywhere. And when you use ajax, you should probably not post to the same page that you are displaying as that will give you the complete html page back. Instead you should post to another script that just processes your post and returns what you need.

Comment: @jeroen, I'm not using any post values, as I haven't been able to populate the post variable via ajax yet. Wrote in question that a `var_dump('$_POST')` returns empty - nothing has been written to it by submitting form. :( been googling this for ages before I posted

Comment: Its not `type: 'POST'`, its `method: 'POST'`, please fix your AJAX function :)

Comment: @Forcefield Tried with both, `$_POST` variable empty both ways.

Comment: Your `.find()` function on serializedData isn't targetting anything, change the values of your DOM elements to `serializedData.find('#projectName')` also trying console logging your serializedData variable before sending the AJAX request so you can determine if it is a valid object. Lastly you are making an AJAX request to same page, which as previously said returns all the HTML markup in your response